# There is no $a, b, n \in N, b \ge 2 $ such $a^{b} = 2017^{n} +43$

Tags: arithmetic, perfect-powers

I found this problem on some training material for a sixth grade Romanian math competition, and I literally have no clue how to approach it. I am not even sure if my interpretation of the problem text is correct, so if someone has a counter example I'll be glad to see it.

Proof that there is no $a, b, n \in N, b \ge 2 $  such $a^{b} =  2017^{n} +43$.
My only try was to look at the last digit of $2017^{n} +43$" and all I could figure it out was that  for $n=4k +2$ last digit will be two, so in this case  the number can't be a perfect square

Thank you

Comment: Reduce mod $8$. Reduce mod $3$.

Comment: Sorry, b must be greater than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a,b,n\in\Bbb{N}$ are such that $a^b=2017^n+43$ then in particular \begin{eqnarray*}
a^b&\equiv&2017^n+43\equiv4\pmod{8},\\
a^b&\equiv&2017^n+43\equiv2\pmod{3},
\end{eqnarray*}
where the first implies $b=2$ and the second implies $b\neq2$, a contradiction.

Comment: I guess I get it, but how I can translate this to a 6 grader?

Comment: @motoras It is well known how to translate "mod" for people without prerequsites, e.g., the clock modulo $12$ etc. Also $a^b$ can be exaplained in very elementary terms with examples first, e.g. $a^2$ means $a\cdot a$ etc. Of course I admit, that $2017$ should be replaced by $2019$ now :)

Comment: Ok, I got it, thank you.